# Typedoc : How to include internal functions for documentation using typedoc

Tags: typescript, typedoc

As I use typedoc to generate documentation it only generates documentation for exported functions and variables even if i set excludeNotExported to false

**Here is my typedocOptions in tsconfig.json**

```
"typedocOptions": {
    "mode": "modules",
    "out": "docs/td",
    "excludeNotExported":false,
}
```

[image: Showing only exported functions and variables I have other internal function like setConfig as well which are not being shown here]

Comment: what does "lib/config.ts" look like and what are the input files set as?

Comment: Thanks, @Chic for response the issue is resolved now

Comment: How Was it resolved? I have the same problem

Comment: @hassanahmed How did you resolve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @sw1337 check answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install a plugin to do this now:

https://github.com/Gerrit0/typedoc-plugin-missing-exports

This will create an "Internals" section for each module with your local vars and functions.

The old way was to set the "mode" but that option is no more.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this Issue 
You have to set the mode of typedoc to 'file' in tsconfig.json and it will document all the non-exported as well as exported variables and functions. 
The other mode is 'module' in which it only generate documentation for exported stuff (i suppose it only checks all declarations appended by keyword export).

Comment: This option has been removed and no longer works.